# sharing a youtube channel with google+

Tags: youtube, google-plus, youtube-channels

I have a YouTube channel that is not connected with Google+, because it was created before YouTube put in the policy that every channel be connected to Google+.  So I'd like to know the following:

1. How do I connect it to Google+?
2. If I can't, and I have to make a new channel, how do I add a video to that channel, and not the first channel
3. Once my channel (and therefore all videos in it) is connected to Google+, how do I share it with just one Google circle and not the whole world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect your YouTube channel to either a Google+ Personal Profile or to a Google+ Page. In general, the latter is the preferred solution.

To connect to a Profile, see https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657961?hl=en

To connect to a Page, see https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2897336?hl=en

Once you have done this, you can make a video private and share it to one of your circles through the Video Info Edit page.
[image]